# How to fix this? pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: get_ytplayer_config: could not find match for config_patterns

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

When I'm trying to download videos using `pytube` I'm getting this error. I'm using the latest version of `pytube`:

```py
raise RegexMatchError(caller="get_ytplayer_config", pattern="config_patterns")
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError:
get_ytplayer_config: could not find match for config_patterns
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be running an old version of pytube.
Run these commands, they **might** fix your problem:

```
python -m pip uninstall pytube pytube3 pytubex
python -m pip install git+https://github.com/nficano/pytube
```